# How to create a sentence with list of position and a list of words

Tags: python

I wanted to create a code which ask a user to enter a list of position on a plain text file, save the position the user entered in the text file as list than ask the user to enter the word each position represent (the same order as the list of position) end re-create the sentence. However when  i run this code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["notepad","list_of_numbers.txt"])
p =open("list_of_numbers.txt","r")
l = p.read()
p.close()
positions = list(l)
subprocess.Popen(["notepad","list_of_words.txt"])
s = open("list_of_words.txt","r")
s.read()
s.close()

sentence = str(s)
print (sentence)


mapping = {}

words = sentence.split()

for (position, word) in zip(positions, words):
    mapping[position] = word


output = [mapping[position] for position in positions]

print(' '.join(output))
```

and i run

```
 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

as list of position

and this as the list of words:

```
 this is a repeated sentence
```

the output should be:

```
 this is a repeated sentence this is a repeated sentence
```

but i get

```
"key error:3"
```

Im think they problem is i didnt store the list of position into a list properly but im not sure. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I unfortunately can't make use of subprocess at the moment (or rather, can't read from files), but turning the files into the lists is your problem. When I hard coded in `positions` and `sentence`, it works like a charm. I suspect the problem is `positions = list(l)`.

Comment: Do you know if  there is any other way to open a plain text file from python?

Comment: You are not assigning anything to `s.read()` and then you are referencing the file descriptor after you've closed it `sentence = str(s)` after `s.close()`. You should look into `with` statements.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["notepad","list_of_numbers.txt"])
with open("list_of_numbers.txt","r") as p:
    l = p.read()
positions = l.split() # see you had to create list by spliting the string

subprocess.Popen(["notepad","list_of_words.txt"])
with open("list_of_words.txt","r") as s:
    sentence = s.read() # you had to assign the string to variable
print (sentence)


mapping = {}

words = sentence.split()

for position, word in zip(positions, words):
    mapping[position] = word


output = [mapping[position] for position in positions]

print(' '.join(output))
```

but also it could be

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["notepad","list_of_numbers.txt"])
with open("list_of_numbers.txt","r") as pos_file:
    positions = pos_file.read().spllit()

subprocess.Popen(["notepad","list_of_words.txt"])
with open("list_of_words.txt","r") as sentence_file:
    words = sentence_file.read().split()

mapping = dict(zip(positions, words))
output = [mapping[position] for position in positions]

print(' '.join(output))
```